# Change Windows 7 Wallpaper with Win32/C++ API (Operation not implemented exception)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

The following code works on Windows 8.1 (tested) but not on Windows 7.

```
std::wstring loc = L"C:\\Users\User\\Desktop\\wallpaper.jpg";
BOOL ret = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)loc.c_str(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

When I run the program on Windows 7 I get the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76E3C41F (KernelBase.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000002:  The requested operation is not implemented.
```

Has anyone came across this before? 
I've had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx and searched Google to no luck.

Comment: First-chance exceptions are not always a problem, as long as something handles it. What happens if you continue execution?

Comment: @JonathanPotter It does continue execution, the wallpaper doesn't change, EDIT: I enabled first chance exceptions in VS and ret = "-858993460"

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC looks like an "uninitialized" pattern

Comment: The wallpaper may not change unless you specify `SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE` as well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan SystemParametersInfoW

Comment: If you see -858993460 then you didn't post your real code.

Comment: @HansPassant ret is "-858993460" in Visual Studio debug (autos tab)

Comment: @Daniel `-858993460` is `0xcccccccc` which is what the debugger initialised the memory to. Looks like you read the value before the call to SPI returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that could be wrong with your code is that you are not compiling for Unicode. And so `SystemParametersInfo` expands to `SystemParametersInfoA` but you pass a wide string. Otherwise your code is correct and does work.

Debugging problems with this particular API call are quite tricky. It doesn't give you much useful feedback. The obvious failure mode is that there is a problem with that specific JPEG file. Perhaps it is not actually a JPEG file in spite of the extension. Or perhaps it uses JPEG features that are not supported by the shell. Or perhaps you got the file name wrong. Those are the sort of things that explain a failure.

I would start debugging this by creating a different JPEG file for test purposes. If that results in success then you know that the issue is the JPEG file that you are using.

Comment: I re exported the image as a JPG (It was a PNG file), I overlooked it at first because it worked in Windows 8.1.. Thanks!